# Passing a single argument to a multi argument function

Tags: c++

I have a variable let say int c in a given function. I want to pass it to the other class.let say it is

`function(int a, int b, int c);`

I want only to pass the third argument while ignore the first two.

**i.e. :**   I just want to pass int c, as `function (c)` and it just pass it to the third argument. I don't want to pass it like `function(0,0,c);` .. Is there any possibility. Please advise.

Comment: `void func(int c, int a = 0, int b = 0);`

Comment: You can write a little wrapper for `function`, like `void my_f( int x ) { function( 0, 0, x )`. Then you can call it like `my_f( 42 )`.

Comment: Make an overload function taking only `c` and call main function from it with default values and `c`

Comment: Use `std::optional.`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to do function overloading. Something like this-

```
function(int a, int b, int c);

function(int c);
```

inside second function you can call first function with appropriate values for `a` and `b`

Answer (score 2):

You can have default values for your function:

```
void function(int c, int a = 0, int b = 0);
```

or you can overload your function:

```
void function(int a, int b, int c) {
    //implementation 1
}

void function(int c) {
    function(0, 0, c);
}
```

You could in both cases use it like this:

```
function(c);
```

**Note** : when we use default values, in function definition the argument with default values must be the last in order for example :

```
void function(int a = 0, int b = 0, int c)
```

is not a valid format.

Answer (score 0):

When you have the situation where `function(c)` is equivalent to `function(0, 0, c)`, it sounds like a poor design. Normally, you can use default argument values for the parameters starting from the end. It would make sense if `function(c)` were equivalent to `function(c, 0, 0)`.

You can accomplish that easily by declaring the function as:

```
void function(int c, int a = 0, int b = 0);
```

I realize that you can accomplish your goal by overloading `function` as:

```
void function(int c)
{
   function(0, 0, c);
}
```

but it still appears to be a poor interface to me.

Answer (score 0):

Imho already with three parameters it is worth to structure them

```
struct foo { 
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};
```

allowing to have a nicer function interface

```
void function(foo f);
```

How does this help? You can provide a default constructor and let the user set only those fields that are not default:

```
struct foo {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    foo() : a(0),b(0),c(0) {}
};

foo f;
f.b = 12;
f.c = 32;
function(f);
```

Now any combination of default / non-defaults is possible.

One could argue that the struct isnt really necessary and the problem is just shifted to the constructor of `foo` or the need to correctly set the members, but I think this is a valid approach that was missing from the other answers. (btw I am not claiming that my example here demonstrates best pratice, but the details would matter on the exact use case)

Comment: should that perhaps be `const foo&`?

Comment: @Default i mentioned "not best pratice". It is just three `int`s, so why bother? Anyhow, I tried to stay close to OPs code who also uses copies